# opencv for-loop with CUDA - parallel processing

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

I am stuck with a problem to have this loop of iterators work on CUDA.
can anyone help here ?

```
std::vector<cv::DMatch>  matches;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> key_pts1, key_pts2;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points1, points2;
for (std::vector<cv::DMatch>::const_iterator itr = matches.begin(); itr!= matches.end(); ++it) 
        {                   
            float x = key_pts1[itr->queryIdx].pt.x;
            float y = key_pts1[itr->queryIdx].pt.y;
            points1.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));                
            x = key_pts2[itr->trainIdx].pt.x;
            y = key_pts2[itr->trainIdx].pt.y;
            points2.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));            
        }
```

This above conversion to CUDA - parallel processing, as I have thought seems quite difficult to me.

```
void dmatchLoopHomography(float *itr, float *match_being, float *match_end, float      *keypoint_1, float *keypoint_2, float *pts1, float *pts2)
{
float x, y;
// allocate memory in GPU memory
unsigned char *mtch_begin, *mtch_end, *keypt_1, *keypt_2, points1, *points2; 
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&mtch_begin, match_being, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&mtch_end, match_end, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&keypt_1, keypoint_1, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&keypt_2, keypoint_2, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&points1, pts1, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&points2, pts2, 0);

//dim3 blocks(16, 16); 
dim3 threads(itr, itr); 
//kernal
dmatchLoopHomography_ker<<<itr,itr>>>(mtch_begin, mtch_end, keypt_1, keypt_2, points1. points2)
cudaThreadSynchronize();    
}
```

and

```
 __global__ void dmatchLoopHomography_ker(float *itr, float *match_being, float *match_end, float *keypoint_1, float *keypoint_2, float *pts1, float *pts2)
{
 //how do I go about it ??
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I noticed that your program consists of moving a `vector<KeyPoint>` into a `vector<Point2f>` structure. OpenCV has a really nice one-liner to do this for you:

```
using namespace cv;
KeyPoint::convert(key_pts1, points1); //vector<KeyPoint> to vector<Point2f>
```

---

Now, let's talk GPU stuff. It turns out that `cudaHostGetDevicePointer()` doesn't allocate memory. You'll want `cudaMalloc()` for allocating memory. For example:

```
//compile with nvcc, not gcc
float* device_matches;
int match_length = matches.end() - matches.begin();
cudaMalloc(&device_matches, match_length*sizeof(float));
//do the same as above for key_pts1, key_pts2, points1, and points2
```

Now, `device_matches` is just a plain C array, not an STL vector. So, you don't have iterators. Instead, you have to just use ordinary array indices. If you really want iterators on the GPU, look at the [Thrust library](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/). Thrust is really handy, but the downside is that Thrust only provides a specific set of pre-baked functions.

---

The bigger question is whether you want to do this particular part of your program on the GPU. I'd recommend using the GPU for really compute-intensive stuff (for example, the actual feature matching), but moving data between data formats (as in your example code) is many orders of magnitude cheaper than feature matching.

Also, bear in mind that you often have to structure your data differently on the GPU than you would on the CPU. This restructuring isn't necessarily computationally expensive, but you'll want to set aside some time to work it out on the whiteboard, tear your hair out, etc. Finally, if you're serious about GPU stuff, it might be worth working through a few simple GPU programming examples (I've enjoyed the [Dr. Dobbs Supercomputing for the Masses tutorials](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/207200659)), taking a GPU/parallel class, or talking to some GPU-hacker friends.

Comment: Thank you @solvingPuzzles for your answer and comments.. Yes I agree with you that feature matching has a higher magnitude of computational requirement. The motive of my question was to understand how to solve this simple problem, and later I can get feature matching on GPU from the information I acquire over the period of my time learning GPU. Thanks for your link to Dr.Dobbs.. yes I have been of-late working on it as well.. btw thanks for the keypoint::convert, dint know it before...

Comment: @timothy nice! As a toy example, I'd recommend coding up matrix multiplication in CUDA. Feel free to "cheat" and look at example code. This code won't be terribly verbose, but you'll learn the boiler-plate CUDA stuff (stuff like `threadIdx`, `blockIdx`, `cudaMemcpy`, `grid`, `block`, etc.)